# In Mapbox Studio how do I make an image for a marker be 400 pixels without getting clipped off?

Tags: mapbox

For Mapbox Studio, I've prepared this Squid drawing I'm going to put in a body of water, similar to the ships in the 'Pirates Return' map.

I have sizes of the drawing in 100,200, and 400 pixels. However, the 400 pixel drawing gets cut off.  The last time I had this problem it was in the buffer settings. However, my buffer-size is now at the max.  So for an image applied to a marker, how do I make it overlap adjacent tiles?

Picture attached for clarification. [image: squid]